# Login user with hashed password

Tags: wordpress, md5

I'm building an API for WordPress on the website.

Part of the API is, of course, signing up and logging in.

I'm aware that WordPress uses a modified version of MD5 to generate the password.  But that only implies if I sent a plain text password which I don't want to.

Is there anyway to hash the password on the client side, then send it to WordPress, and use the hashed password to login/signup?

Comment: hash != encryption. what benefit will you gain by hashing the password in client side?

Comment: not sending it in plain text form to the server side

Comment: you should never send the password from the server to the client. i think that the answer you are looking for is JWT, or complete authentication solutions like OAuth that will make it possible to remember the user, stateless, without exposing anything while been able to scale. please read about jwt and oauth https://jwt.io/ , https://oauth.net/2/

Comment: Not from server to client, the other way around. Sending the user auth info to the server to check it.

Comment: there is no reason to hash/encrypt the credentials that are been sent from the client. you should instead make sure you are using secured connection (HTTPS), using best practices of responses from login page (for example, don't give any clues for what was incorrect - the password or the user), make it harder to brute force with request limitations. if you are using cookies to store the state, make sure you use only secured cookies (https only). generally, just try to follow the best practices in the market, even if the implementation is bit different